# I made a marketing research - VS - I did a marketing research

Tags: verbs, do-support, causative-make

Make VS do

I made a marketing research - VS - I did a marketing research

Marketing Research= a written business report most of the time printed and delivered to people in business meetings

Do you use "make" or "do" in regards an activity that is intangible but it produces something tangible like a written report?

Comment: I don't think you can '_make_' a research. You can make an analysis, but not a research.

Comment: *Research* is a mass noun, so you wouldn't use the indefinite article with it. And you would *do* it, not *make* it.

Comment: You do the research and then after you've done the research you make your report about what you found while doing the research.

Comment: You can also **conduct** research.  And you can use **research** as a transitive verb.  *We **researched** the market for self-driving cars in Antarctica.*

Comment: Research is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

The verb here would be *to do*, so *did* is the past participle you would use here. However, as comments have pointed out, research is an uncountable noun so you would not do *a marketing research* but would do *marketing research*.

Also, typically research into the state of a market, which is what sounds like you are saying would be called *market research* rather than *marketing research*.

*Marketing research* may discuss the activities or methods of a company's marketing department, marketing or advertising methods or alternatives,how to sell something, advertising choices, etc.

*Market research* may discuss what people are buying, what products exist (or not), if there may be a demand for a product, what gaps exist in the market, etc.